# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function (anonymous function)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am getting an error in my developer screen when running the code underneath , in php pages when you call  or  the javascript is suppose to put an icon next to the message. In IE it works fine but in Chrome and other browsers getting:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function jsfunctions.php:92
  dowarnerr jsfunctions.php:92
  AddIcons jsfunctions.php:180
  (anonymous function)
```

Any ideas what this is and why?

------------------------------------jsfunctions.php------------------------

```
function AddIcons()
{
  if (typeof(error)=='object') 
 {
  dowarnerr(error,'Error');
 }
 if (typeof(warning)=='object') 
 {
 dowarnerr(warning,'Warning');
 }
 }
function doerror(err, etype)
{
  msg = err.innerHTML;
  if (etype=='Error') {
    err.innerHTML = '<img id=icon src=/images/err.gif>' + msg;
                      }
  else {
    err.innerHTML = '<img id=icon src=/images/warning.gif>' + msg;
       }
}





function dowarnerr(obj, etype)
{
   if(typeof(obj.innerHTML) == 'string') {
   doerror(obj, etype);
   }
   else 
   {
   for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
   doerror(obj(i), etype);
   }
   }
}





------------------------------------menu_config.php----------------------------------



<HEAD>
  <LINK REL="StyleSheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="/styles.php"></LINK>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="/scripts/jsfunctions.php"></script>
</HEAD>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
AddIcons();
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Well, apparently `error` (or `warning`) passed to `dowarnerr` in `AddIcons` is not a function but an object, hence `obj(i)` in `dowarnerr` throws an error. You can only call functions, not objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if the first arg passed into dowarnerr() function is an object you cannot use `for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)` statement. You have to use foreach:

```
for (var propName in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
    doerror(obj[propName], etype);
  }
}
```